# AzCopy configure blob name

Tags: azure, azcopy

Is there a way to specify the generated blob name when converting AzureTable to AzureBlob

> AzCopy /Source:$source /Dest:$container /SourceKey:$SourceKey
>   /Destkey:$Destkey /V:./azcopy.log

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use option /Manifest to specify the prefix of exported file names.

> AzCopy /?:Manifest
>
> /Manifest:     Specifies the manifest file name for the table export and import operation. **This option is optional during the export operation, AzCopy will generate a manifest file with predefined name if this option is not specified.** This option is required during the import operation for locating the data files.

The exported files will follow the naming convention:

```
<manifest name>_<volume index>_<CRC>.json
```

Comment: Does my reply solve your question? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others find and resolve similar problem quickly.